# slurmstepd: error: Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) using R Terra on HPC

Tags: raster, r, terra

I am using Terra on a HPC with the below code to count the number of pixels of each class of a raster within a polygon shapefile.

```
library(terra)

#open files in terra native format
rastermap<-rast("path_to_my_raster")
shapefilemap<-vect("path_to_my_shapefile")


# perform extraction
ext<-extract(rastermap, shapefilemap)

View(ext)
```

At the last step (calculating ext) I keep getting this error message:

> 'slurmstepd: error: Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) in StepId=5103776.batch. Some of your processes may have been killed by the cgroup out-of-memory handler.'

which I understand means I have reached the maximum memory allowed.The raster file is about 40GB itself.

I have tried running with up to 200GB RAM. I have tried using terraOptions memfrac and memmax as I have seen suggested on other threads but neither worked. I still get the same message.

This job is not suitable for parallel processing as far as I am aware. I have also set the CPU for the job to 12 but I know R by default will only use 1.

I am pretty new to using R/HPC for this type of tsk. Is there anything  else I can try?

Comment: How complex is your shapefile? Is it just one feature? If not, try it with one feature, and then that can be parallelised. If it fails on memory with one feature then split the raster into smaller tiles, and parallelise over tiles, combining the extractions from each tile in a separate job...

Comment: This is basically what exactextractr does, minus the parallel bit.

Comment: Yes, try the `exactextractr` package!

Comment: Thank you! The shapfile is just a single polygon so very simple. 


' Exactextractr ' seems promising however I am getting the below error indicating some sort of mismatch of the installation of the package

'
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f9bc4161040, cause 'memory not mapped'
'

Comment: I use `dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive = TRUE)  # create personal library
.libPaths(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"))  # add to the path` to download new packages directly within the R script that I send to the slurm scheduler.